# Soma de um intervalo específico em um array PHP

Tags: php

Estou a estudar arrays e não consigo ir adiante nesse caso. Eu devo somar todos os valores de cada chave, entre um intervalo específico.

Exemplo 1: entre 'valor1' e 'valor3'. O resultado esperado é: 31.5
Exemplo 2: entre 'valor4' e 'valor6'. O resultado esperado é: 66.2

O código que define o valor que vai nas chaves e o array montado é esse:

```
$valor1 = 10;
$valor2 = 12;
$valor3 = 9.5;
$valor4 = 18;
$valor5 = 36.2;
$valor6 = 12;
$valores = array('valor1' => $valor1, 'valor2' => $valor2, 'valor3' => $valor3, 'valor4' => $valor2, 'valor5' => $valor5, 'valor6' => $valor6);
```

Eu já consegui definir através do código abaixo, qual será o intervalo que deverá ser feito a soma.

```
$valorinicial = 'valor2';
$valorfinal = 'valor4';
$posicaoinicial = array_flip(array_keys($valores))[$valorinicial];
$posicaofinal = array_flip(array_keys($valores))[$valorfinal];
```

Fiz algumas tentativas, a última foi essa (sem sucesso):

```
$soma = 0;
foreach ($valores as $chave => $valor) {
   if ($chave >= $posicaoinicial && $chave <= $posicaofinal) {
      $soma += $valor;
   }
}
echo $soma;
```

Comment: Existe alguma razão para você estar usando array associativo ao invés de array indexado?

Comment: Existe sim, a associação define a sequência a lógica do exercício. Esses valores (valor1, valor2, valor3) ordena o array. Eu vou ter que aplicar em uma situação prática que é a seguinte: "Um trem tem 6 vagões, cada um transporta uma quantidade diferente de pessoas. Somar a quantidade de pessoas totais em um intervalo de vagões. Ex: entre o vagão 2 e o vagão 4.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como em PHP a ordem dos elementos de um [array associativo](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php) é definida pela ordem qual os elementos são inseridos nesse array associativo, implicando ser possível extrair um sub array delimitado por duas chaves com esse algoritmo:

- Com [`array_keys()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-keys.php) obtenha um array indexado contendo todas as chaves do array associativo.
- Com [`array_search()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-search.php) encontre os índice inicial e final do intervalo que deseja somar.
- Com [`array_slice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-slice.php) e um pouco de algebra linear extraia o sub array delimitado pelas duas chaves.

Então some os valores desse sub array com [`array_sum()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-sum.php).

> **Nota:** Esse algoritmo não faz nenhum tipo de verificação de validade
> das chaves ou intervalo buscado.

```
<?php

$valor1 = 10;
$valor2 = 12;
$valor3 = 9.5;
$valor4 = 18;
$valor5 = 36.2;
$valor6 = 12;
$valores = array(
  'valor1' => $valor1, 
  'valor2' => $valor2, 
  'valor3' => $valor3, 
  'valor4' => $valor4,                            //Correção: o valor original no exemplo é 'valor4' => $valor2 
  'valor5' => $valor5, 
  'valor6' => $valor6
);

$valorinicial = 'valor2';
$valorfinal = 'valor4';

$keys = array_keys($valores);                   //Obtém o array indexado contendo contendo as chaves de $valores.
$inicial = array_search($valorinicial, $keys);  //Obtém o índice da chave $valorinicial.
$final = array_search($valorfinal, $keys);      //Obtém o índice da chave valorfinal.

//Extrai de $valores um sub array que vai do elemento $inicial até $final - $inicial + 1.
$intervalo = array_slice($valores, $inicial, $final - $inicial + 1); 
   
$total = array_sum($intervalo);                //Soma os valores do sub array $intervalo.

echo $total;                                  //39.5
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repli.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/subarray#main.php)</sup>

Comment: Cara, muito bom. Muito obrigado. Uma verdadeira aula! Se permite uma pergunta. Como ficaria caso eu não usasse a primeira posição nessa soma? E caso não usasse a última posição? Seria isso?

$inicial = array_search($valorinicial, $keys) + 1;  para ignorar a primeira chave

$intervalo = array_slice($valores, $inicial, $final - $inicial); // para ignorar a última chave

Comment: Sim, no caso você teria intervalos abertos em um dos extremos.